# Intuition behind complex inner product

Tags: lie-groups, inner-products

Let $f_n : \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb R^{2n}$ be defined by 
$$(x_1 + iy_1, x_2 + iy_2, \dots) \mapsto (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, \dots )$$

I am having trouble believing that

$$ \langle X, Y\rangle_{\mathbb C} = \langle f(X) , f(Y)\rangle_{\mathbb R}+ i \langle f(X),f(iY) \rangle_{\mathbb R}$$

The map $f$ is a linear isomorphism. The equation above looks like the right hand side has twice the magnitude (absolute value) of the left hand side. Could someone help me see that they are equal?

(Here the complex inner product is defined as $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_n x_n \overline{y_n}$)

Comment: How do you define the complex inner product? It seems to me this question is central to understanding the question.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I edited my question.

Comment: Write down the complex inner product in terms of the real and imaginary parts of the components. Separate into real and imaginary part of the inner product. Compare with the expression involving the real inner products.

Comment: @DanielFischer I did it but it is wrong. For one complex dimension I get: $$ \langle x + iy, a + ib\rangle = (x + iy)(a - ib) = (xa + yb) + i (ay - xb)$$ and
$$ \langle f(x+iy), f(a + ib)\rangle = \langle (x,y),(a,b)\rangle = xa + yb$$

Comment: And $$\langle f(x+iy), f(i(a+ib))\rangle = \langle f(x+iy), f(-b+ia)\rangle = \langle (x,y), (-b,a)\rangle = -xb + ya.$$ That looks like the imaginary part of $\langle x+iy,a+ib\rangle_\mathbb{C}$ to me.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you! Sometimes I make such stupid mistakes.

Comment: It is neat how seeing it for one-complex dimension almost immediately extends to $n$-complex dimensions.

Comment: @DanielFischer But I still don't see why it should be true. Is there some geometric intuition for this? Something that makes it obvious?